# C# PrintDocument print image

Tags: c#, zebra-printers, printdocument

I have been trying to print a barcode image via the label printer. but the image that is printing using the SATO CG408 printer is very small. Here is the code as it is currently.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("Custom", 100, 77);

            //We want potrait. 
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;
            pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
            pd.Print();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static void PrintPage(object o, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        //System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"c:\test\test.png");
        //img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
        //e.Graphics.DrawImage(img,0,0);

        int printHeight = 450;
        int printWidth = 400;
        int leftMargin = 20;
        int rightMargin = 0;
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"c:\test\test.png");
        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(leftMargin, rightMargin, printWidth, printHeight));
    }
```

Not really sure why the image is displaying small. The image that is being printed is generated at a different server. The image size is 2480px by 1748px.

[image]

Can some one please help. Trying to solve this for the past few days. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should set your direction ...
try this:

```
pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove margins

```
int leftMargin = 0;
int rightMargin = 0;
```

and check imgage ratio: 2480px / 1748px ~ 1.419, 400px / 450px~ 0,889. So maybe try:

```
int printHeight = 420;
int printWidth = 596;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the printer had the wrong dimensions set up for the paper. Thats why it was printing so small. Feel silly now. Thanks all for help.